# Why is my click event not working for a button in a script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-edge

I have a button event enabled & called on change of a dropdownlist value. It is not working on Edge, but working completely fine on other browsers. 
The button is not doing anything, nothing happens on click. I debugged, the control goes there, even twice, but still the event doesn't fire. 
Any help would be appreciated.

html -

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.PensionPayrollSchemeDesc, new { TabIndex = 1, id = "pension-payroll-schemes-list" })

$("#pension-payroll-schemes-list").on(
        "change",
        {
            url: "SelectedSchemeProcessingButtons",
            model: decodes
        },
        onSchemeSelection);


// Event handler for changing the selected scheme
function onSchemeSelection(evt) {
    resetMessages(true);
    setProcessButtons(evt.data.url, false);  
}

// Using the selected scheme, check the current status and set the buttons accordingly    
function setProcessButtons(actionUrl, refresh) {
        let scheme = $("#pension-payroll-schemes-list").val();
        if (scheme === '') {
            setFileNetCaseRefState();
            return;
        }

        let selection = $("#PensionPayrollSchemeNumber").val();
        if (selection && selection > 0) {
            $('#processingModal').foundation('open');
            setFileNetCaseRefState(selection);
            let suppressInfoMessage = refresh;
            return $.ajax({
                url: actionUrl,
                data: antiforgeryModule.addAntiForgeryToken({ payrollSchemeNumber: selection, suppressInfoMessage: suppressInfoMessage }),
                type: 'POST',
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    $('#processingModal').foundation('close');
                    errorHandling.displayError(xhr, status, error, 'globalFormError');
                    errorHandling.clearSuccess('globalFormSuccess');
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#processingModal').foundation('close');
                    if (response) {
                        $('#actionButtons').html(response);
                    }
                    setActions();
                }
            });
        }
}


// bind an action to the specified button click event
function setAction(id, action, closeModal) {
    let button = $("#" + id);
    button.off("click").on("click", action, processAction);
}

// Set the process button actions
function setActions() {
    setAction("doYearEnd", {
        url: YearEndJobAction,
        override: false,
        model: decodes,
        closeModal: false,
        next: function () {
            displaySuccess(YearEndSubmittedMessage);
        }
    });
}


// Using the selected scheme, check the current status and set the buttons accordingly    
function setProcessButtons(actionUrl, refresh) {
        let scheme = $("#pension-payroll-schemes-list").val();
        if (scheme === '') {
            setFileNetCaseRefState();
            return;
        }

        let selection = $("#PensionPayrollSchemeNumber").val();
        if (selection && selection > 0) {
            return $.ajax({
                url: actionUrl,
                data: antiforgeryModule.addAntiForgeryToken({ payrollSchemeNumber: selection }),
                type: 'POST',
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    errorHandling.displayError(xhr, status, error, 'globalFormError');
                    errorHandling.clearSuccess('globalFormSuccess');
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response) {
                        $('#actionButtons').html(response);
                    }
                    setActions();
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: how can we reproduce your problem?

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem, can you post the Enough code (include the html element and related Script) to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've added some more code, please see.  @cloned

Comment: I've added some more code, please see.  @zhi-lv-msft

Comment: What is `@Html.EditorFor`, and what type of syntax is `new { TabIndex = 1, id = "pension-payroll-schemes-list" }`? That does not look like valid Javascript syntax to me.

Answer (score 0):

> @Html.EditorFor(x => x.PensionPayrollSchemeDesc, new { TabIndex = 1,
> id = "pension-payroll-schemes-list" })

Please try to use the F12 developer tools to check the Html element and the custom attributes. From the above code, it seems that you want to add some custom attributes (TabIndex and id), if using F12 developer tools to check the HTML elements, the result as below:

[image]

we can see that the id attribute is "PensionPayrollSchemeDesc", instead of "pension-payroll-schemes-list". So, the change event not working.

Try to modify the code as below:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PensionPayrollSchemeDesc, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "pension-payroll-schemes-list", TabIndex = 1 } })
```

After rendering, the result as below:

[image]

Finally, based on the id property to attach the change event on it.

Comment: This issue is only appearing in edge, the same code is working fine in IE 11. Also, this is the DOM for your reference, the ID seems ok to me -

Comment: <input name="PensionPayrollSchemeDesc" tabindex="1" class="text-box single-line ui-autocomplete-input valid" id="pension-payroll-schemes-list" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="pension-payroll-schemes-list-error" type="text" value="" data-val="true" data-val-validautocompleteentry="The Payroll Scheme field has an invalid value." data-val-required="The Payroll Scheme field is required." data-val-length-max="30"  data-mf-initial-value="" data-lov-name="SchemeDescLov" data-auto-complete="True" autocomplete="off">

Comment: Try to set debuggers in the setProcessButtons function, setAction function and the setActions function, then using F12 developer Debugger tools to debug the script steps by steps, make sure these functions are executed. And you could also use the Console tools to check whether there have some error? Besides, please try to clear the Edge browser data (cache, history), then retest it.

Comment: Based on your code, I have created a sample (the code [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/qt8n1s3r/), I removed some duplicate function (such as : setProcessButtons) and the not defined variable and mode), it works well on my side, please check it.